# Setup of touchscreen in Linux

Tags: x11, gentoo, touch-screen

recently I got a touchscreen ELO ts-1515, I'm using Gentoo in a machine with an Intel Atom processor, and my desktop manager is LXDE, I get install X11 server and drivers without any problem, the problem is the touchscreen.

The touchscreen only works aprox. 80% of total area, (the area working is located in the center of touchscreen), the second problem is the y axis are inverted (I resolve this with `xinput`).

I read the wiki of Gentoo and ELO touchscreen, and say execute `X -configure`, When I make this, in the end of command mark error and says "number of created screens does not match number of detected devices".

Comment: And you made sure that 100% of the total area of that [screen](http://www.elotouch.com/Products/LCDs/1515L/) works on another OS for instance i.e. that the hardware is not defective? You're using [this](http://www.gentoo-wiki.info/Elo_Touchscreen) 2008 wiki? So that's the USB model? There is indication these screens can [misbehave](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/commit/?id=d8e5aec8d9e8754e4b4e12d9b61dc89fe229349b), have you contacted the manufacturer? Please update your Q accordingly.

Comment: really i don't be sure, yesterday i probe with mint live cd and the behaivor as equal, maybe i can get other touchscreen i put here my results

Comment: well, today i get a windows, and the problem not is the touch, with windows, the tocuscreen work correctly

Comment: What input driver do you use: libinput or evdev?

Answer (score 1):

I finally got good behavior of my touchscreen with the following command:

```
  xinput set-int-prop 11 "Evdev Axis Calibration" 32 440 3600 480 3500
```

I discovered the values by accident. When I wrote 300 in xmin instead of 30 (usually the values are under 200), and so I experimented with different values in every field and I believe these values are the best.